# networkx graph with csv input and plotly output

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

**Some background...**

I am a beginner to python and networkx...

I have a csv file with multiple columns.

I have extracted the columns that contained the sender and receiver addresses and put them into lists like so:

```
with open('file.csv,'r') as csv_file:
    lines = csv_file.readlines()

sip = []
dip = []

for line in lines:
    data = line.split(',')
    sip.append(data[9])
    dip.append(data[10])
nodes=list(set().union(sip,dip))
edges=list(set().union(list(zip(sip,dip))))
```

A quick print of my G.nodes() and G.edges() 
gives me the following output:

```
edges = [('AddressA','AddressB'),('AddressA','AddressC')]
nodes = ['AddressA','AddressB','AddressC']
```

where *edges = [('senderaddress','receiveraddress')]*

**My goal**

I wish to use networkx to plot out connections between senders and receivers.

I am using this [page](https://plot.ly/python/network-graphs/#reference) as reference.

This is my current code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import networkx as nx
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

#######CREATE NODES/EDGES#############
G=nx.Graph()
nodes=list(set().union(sip,dip))
edges=list(set().union(list(zip(sip,dip))))
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    line=dict(width=0.5,color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_trace['x'] += tuple([x0, x1, None])
    edge_trace['y'] += tuple([y0, y1, None])

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    text=[],
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=10,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line=dict(width=2)))

for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_trace['x'] += tuple([x])
    node_trace['y'] += tuple([y])

# ########COLOR NODES#########
for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node_trace['marker']['color']+=tuple([len(adjacencies[1])])
    node_info = '# of connections: '+str(len(adjacencies[1]))
    node_trace['text']+=tuple([node_info])

# ########CREATE GRAPH#########
fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                title='<br>Network graph made with Python',
                titlefont=dict(size=16),
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="Python code: <a href='https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/'> https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/</a>",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False)))

fig.show()
```

However, I end up with this error:

```
  x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
KeyError: 'pos'
```

A print(pos) showed that it was empty:

```
{}
```

I'm not sure where the error lies. I believe it may have started since I populated the graph with nodes and edges. I am not sure how to rectify it though...

Comment: I have the same question. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1):

I modified some part of the posted code. 
With nodes and edges given directly, from the output shown in question.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import networkx as nx
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

x = []
y = []
G=nx.Graph()
```

> ```
> #from question
> edges = [('AddressA','AddressB'),('AddressA','AddressC')]
> nodes = ['AddressA','AddressB','AddressC']
> ```

```
print ("nodes =", nodes)
print ("edges =", edges)

G.add_nodes_from(nodes, word1 = 'word2')

pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'word1')
G.add_edges_from(edges)
print("pos = ", pos)
```

This will print pos

Note1:

If I G.add_edges_from before pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'word1') ; 
then pos = []

If I assign pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'word1') before G.add_edges_from  then pos will print correctly

I get output as follows:

```
nodes = ['AddressA', 'AddressB', 'AddressC']
edges = [('AddressA', 'AddressB'), ('AddressA', 'AddressC')]
pos =  {'AddressA': 'word2', 'AddressB': 'word2', 'AddressC': 'word2'}
```